# How to Create proxy classes in doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

I'm using doctrine orm (v2) to my project but i'm sticking with generate proxy classes. so How to create proxy classes in doctrine. any body please help me this issue.

Thank you,

Comment: Which version of doctrine?  Big difference between D2 and D1.

Comment: Please guys any body help to this issue...

Answer (score 0):

in cli you can use

```
doctrine orm:generate-proxies
```